# How to keep div size constant on zoom in and zoom out?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

take a look at this slider on [this website](http://www.needforspeed.com/), and press **CTRL** + **+** or **CTRL** + **-** *(zoom in, zoom out)* and you'll understand what I mean.

How is that possible, keep the same size for the slider and its content when we zoom the page.

I guess it uses any jQuery/JavaScript script, I'm not sure. Thank you.

Comment: You can check which Javascipt event is fired during zooming if there is any ofcourse.

Comment: You could also use percentage values which are not affected by zooming

Comment: @CarlosBergenDyck won't it follow container size then?

Comment: CarlosBergenDyck's advice doesn't work, keeping in mind that images have their own resolution.

Comment: @IrinelIovu which carousel plugin is that? Maybe it have its own `resize`-method?

Comment: @yckart it is using https://github.com/richardscarrott/jquery-ui-carousel

Comment: @IrinelIovu The scroller you use has its own `refresh`-method: https://github.com/richardscarrott/jquery-ui-carousel#refresh-rs-carouselcarouselrefresh I updated my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17324937/1250044

Answer (score 0):

You can simply recalculate the slider-dimensions with an event-handler, like this:

```
$(document).on('keydown', function(e){
    if(e.ctrlKey) {

        if(e.which === 187) {
            // zoom-in, +
        }

        if(e.which === 189) {
            // zoom-out, -
        }

    }
});
```

**Update**

I noted that you can simply you the `resize`-event, to check if the window-size is changed:

```
$(window).on('resize', function(){
    alert(true)
});
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/aZagW/1/

**Update2**

The scroller you use has its own `refresh`-method:

> Refreshes carousel based on new state. The carousel can be made responsive by calling this method on the windows resize event.

https://github.com/richardscarrott/jquery-ui-carousel#refresh-rs-carouselcarouselrefresh

Comment: That only covers zooming in and out with the keyboard, not the mouse.

Comment: That wouldn't work well enough at all, think about, there are many different screen resolutions.

Comment: @IrinelIovu See my [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17324742/how-to-keep-div-size-constant-on-zoom-in-and-zoom-out/17324937#comment25130233_17324742).

Comment: @yckart I did, but, how to keep the size constant? That's my real question. http://jsfiddle.net/9RPdL/

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this

```
window.onresize = function()
{
    var elementWidth = window.innerWidth
    var element = document.getElementById('element')
    element.style.width = parseInt(elementWidth)/2 // for example if you want it always be half of page 
}
```